# Want 10 rows in every page while binding to a repeater

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater which is bound to a data source having 500 rows.I don't want it for paging.
Simple when the rows are coming to repeater they grow down.So ,suppose i have  10 pages, each page having 50 rows in the browser print preview, when i am printing the document with ctrl+p command.

so,is there any way , so that my page will contain only 10 rows and with header and footer in every page.

Thanks
Manas

Comment: To clear out, you try to find a way to add some extra data on the repeater every 10 rows ? Eg an extra header each 10 rows ?

Comment: yes you are true.but how can i do this in a repeater.

Answer (score 1):

You can add inside the repeater an `if, then, Write` call, using also a public integer value from code behind, as:

```
public int ImetritisReapeter = 1;
```

and on the page:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rMyID" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <% if (ImetritisReapeter++ % 10 == 0) { 
        Response.Write("<br>Extra header ever 10 lines");
    } %>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```